# Парсинг сайта explorer.solana.com

Tags: php, парсер

Есть сайт https://explorer.solana.com/tx/3s8UeALNDH4HZ4FQ3TQsc3kBPeww4dweaGPaqTpPMUhpfjZpabpW9p7EjMUbzVYT6jYCVezbRKqwQCJ9cYu5QREW

Подскажите решение парсинга на php.
Через file_get_contents, curl, отслеживание XHR не удается решить задачу.
В какую сторону "копать"?

Comment: А почему бы просто не найти сайт где это можно сделать по API?

Comment: да, можно. Но это крайний вариант. Хотелось бы обойтись без сторонних сервисов, библиотек.